How to print emojis using Pascal on Windows cmd/powershell
According to this table the UTF8 code for the smiley emoji is: F0 9F 98 81.
I attempt to write this output to the console, to no avail:
Program emojii;

{$apptype CONSOLE}

Begin
  WriteLn(#$F0#$9F#$98#$81);
End.

The response I get is jargon: ≡ƒÿü
I'm using Windows Terminal Powershell that supports emojiis, as can be seen in the image below:

I'm using FreePascal: Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.2 [2024/02/26] for x86_64. I build with the following command:
fpc emojii.pas


Does this answer your question? Diacritics in a Pascal console APP?

@KaiBurghardt no. I've figured it out and left an answer.

By default Windows CMD and Powershell use code page 437, which doesn't support emojis.
The solution is to use SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8) to change the consoles code page to UTF8.
I've included an example below using both UTF8 and UTF16 codepoints.
Program Emoji;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows;
  
Var
  U8Emoji: String;
  U16Emoji: WideString;
  Converted: String;
Begin
  //  emoji UTF8 and UTF16 codepoints
  U8Emoji := Char($F0) + Char($9F) + Char($98) + Char($81);
  U16Emoji := WideChar($D83D) + WideChar($DE01);
  
  // Convert UTF16 to UTF8
  Converted := UTF8Encode(U16Emoji);

  // Set the Windows console codepage to UTF8. By default CMD and Powershell
  // use code page 437: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);  

  // Prints  emoji 
  WriteLn(U8Emoji);
  WriteLn(Converted);
End.

You will need a font that supports emojis. Windows 11 uses the Segoe UI Emoji font by default.

That's just personal experience and can vary a lot in other environments - there's no guarantee the console uses a font/multiple fonts to display all graphemes (which differs as per Windows version) and there's no guarentee every user didn't set a different default. Try combined characters and discover the limits. Proper names are: UTF-8 and UTF-16 (with hyphen), and emoji (one i).

Your pascal program and its result is OK.

Change your global windows encoding settings or your shell settings to use utf-8 encoding. Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8.
If your encoding is different and you must support that encoding, you must change your code. Unfortunately I don't have any M$ Windows PC. But your emoji codes could be written as:

UTF-8:  $F0 $9F $98 $81     (Hex)
UTF-8:  &360 &237 &230 &201 (Octal)
UTF-16: $D83D $DE01         (Hex)
UTF-32: $1F601              (Hex)


I figured out windows uses UCS4, so I had to use SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8).

Sorry, I meant cmd and Powershell uses Code Page 437 by default. Was unable to edit previous comment.

@BugHunterUK You can always delete your comment(s) and add a new one - there's no need to keep a wrong one forever. Delete both an post a new correct comment.

"Stop commenting" comments the comment spammer. Quite ironic, @BugHunterUK.
